# Thread 1: Exc Bad Instruction in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

With the code below, I want to print the name and the price in each table cell. The build is done without any problem, but when I run the app, it says `Bad Instruction` error in the `var item1 = arrData[i]["name"]`

Here's the full code:

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

let arrData: [[String:Any]] = [
    ["name": "spiderman", "price": 5000],
    ["name": "superman", "price": 15000],
    ["name": "batman", "price": 3000],
    ["name": "wonder woman", "price": 25000],
    ["name": "gundala", "price": 15000],
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "Cell"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)

    var i = 0

    while i <= arrData.count {
        var item1 = arrData[i]["name"]
        var item2 = arrData[i]["price"]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(item1) \(item2)"
        i = i + 1
    }
    return cell!

}

}
```

Comment: Remove the while loop and read more about table views. That delegate method doesn't run once for the table view, it runs once for every individual cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of while loop use `indexPath.row` to use show proper data at each row in your `UITableView`. And use reusable cell like below:

```
let identifier = "Cell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    tableview.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

    let item1 = arrData[indexPath.row]["name"]
    let item2 = arrData[indexPath.row]["price"]
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(item1!) \(item2!)"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error at the return cell! line

Comment: @Nodoodle I have updated code to solve your problem which is most likely occur due to not initialising cell properly.

Comment: thanks! worked properly, but can the "optional" text that printed before the actual item be removed?

Comment: Yes you can unwrap optional value by placing ! after variable name like     cell.textLabel?.text = "\(item1!) \(item2!)"

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Fix this piece `while i < arrData.count`. Index is out of bounds.

Comment: This is only half of the OP's problem.

Comment: I know about, just full cycle on each cell iteration. All cells will set last item of data.

Answer (score 0):

When you use instruction i <= arrData.count for 5th index you will get crash. You should change to, or better to use for in instruction

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let identifier = "Cell"

var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)

var i = 0

while i < arrData.count {
    var item1 = arrData[i]["name"]
    var item2 = arrData[i]["price"]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(item1) \(item2)"
    i = i + 1
}
return cell!
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Subscript of array is start from zero. It means the first element is not `arrData[1]` but `arrData[0]`. so `while i <= arrData.count` will cause out of bounds of array.

Try `while i < arrData.count`

PS, codes in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is wired, why you add a while loop? it will cause all cell of table view looks same.

Comment: This is only half of the OP's problem.